# Use Basic Javascript Function to Insert Code into Div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to call up an "example.js" file containing an image gallery (the bulk of the code for the gallery, seeing as how i will have 3 to choose from) using:

```
<img src="img.jpg" onClick="thisAction()" />
```

What I want to do is place all of the contained "example.js" code within a div elsewhere in the page. I have a seperate javascript.js file that references the thisAction() function, but I can't seem to figure out where to go from there, nothing is working. 
I have tried a load function, and I've delved into ajax, not really knowing what I'm doing... Please help!

---

Ok, so just to clarify ^^^above^^^, I am not actually trying to call in any javascript in my "example.js", I was simply instructed to do so, because of some reason I can't recall that had to do with recognizing the formatting.... because what I actually want is some html to be inserted, which includes some divs. What i'd like, if possible, is to insert all the code in "example.html" which may contain something like this:

```
<div id="navbuttonleftcontainer"></div>
    <div id="image_holder"><img src="examplepic.jpg" /></div>
<div id="navbuttonrightcontainer"></div>
```

into a div elsewhere on the page in my existing "gallery.html" by calling the function with the

```
<img src="examplenavpic.jpg" onClick="thisAction() />
```

tag.

The closest I've been able to come was with this:

```
function thisAction()
{
$('#divonmygalleryhtml').html('gallery1.html');
}
```

But this doesn't actually spit out the above mentioned example.html code, it just puts the text "gallery.html" into the div. I've tryed simply copying all the code from example.html and replacing it with

```
function thisAction()
{
$('#divonmygalleryhtml').html('
<div id="navbuttonleftcontainer"></div>
<div id="image_holder"><img src="examplepic.jpg" /></div>
<div id="navbuttonrightcontainer"></div>
');
}
```

But that won't do a thing... Ive tried the last 2 suggestions with no luck... Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I'm Not too clear on what you want? Do you want to display the content of a `js` file on a div? You'll need server side programming for this.

Comment: do you have access to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i get you right. With jQuery's AJAX - function and the HTML - function you can reload code from the server and place it in a div on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function({

    function thisAction(){

        $.ajax({
        url: "/pathToFile/example.js",
        cache: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
        $("#targetDiv").html( data );
        });

    }

    thisAction();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a external javascript file you would do

```
function thisAction(){
var divfill = getElementById(targetDiv);
var newscript;
newscript.src ="example.js";
divfill.innerHTML = (newscript);
}
```

Hope that works :).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use jQuery then you can use the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the contents of a remote source to an element

```
function thisAction() {
    $('#divonmygalleryhtml').load('example.html');
}
```